# REACT Create line through completed items TODO LIST app

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble creating a line through completed items on my Todo list app

I have tried a few different ways of completing this task but just started using react last week and cannot get my handleCheck() function to create a line through completed items.  I will provide the codepen url - any help would be greatly appreciated! Everything else works fine and this was kind of a stretch goal as I am new to JS/React/coding in general.  I think my issue stems from the fact that my initial state was not set up in a way that would make updating state in an individual array element simple to do / the fact that I'm trying to update state of one dynamically created element in an array which is hard for me to conceptualize right now :(

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/jackgilbertx/pen/gNOqGY

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      items: [],
      completed: false
    };
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);

  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.term.length < 34){
    this.setState({
      term: '',
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
    });
  }else{
    alert('limit to 33 characters')
  }
  }

  handleRemove(index, event){
    if(confirm('are you sure?')){

    let todoArray = this.state.items;
    todoArray.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({
      items: todoArray
    })
  }}
 handleCheck(index, event){
  // code to create line through completed item
 }


  render() {

    return (

      <div className="container">
        <h1>To Do App</h1>
        <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input className="input" value={this.state.term} onChange= 
  {this.onChange} />
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="list-group">

            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
                   <li  

                     class="list-group-item"
                     key={index}>
                     <input id="chk" onChange={this.handleCheck} 
type="checkbox" /> {item}      
                     <button 
                       className="btn btn-info"
                     onClick= 
{event=>this.handleRemove(index,event)}>X</button>
                     </li>)}                      
       </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize your `completed` state as an object and keep the completed todo indexes there. As an example, your state will change like that when you toggle the todos:

```
completed: {
    0: true,
    1: false,
}
```

The code part is doing that:

```
handleCheck(index) {
  // code to create line through completed item
  this.setState(state => ({
    completed: { ...state.completed, [index]: !state.completed[index] }
  }));
}
```

We are spreading the completed state and manipulate the index of todos as `true` and `false`.

Working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: "",
      items: [],
      completed: {},
    };
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.term.length < 34) {
      this.setState({
        term: "",
        items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
      });
    } else {
      alert("limit to 33 characters");
    }
  };

  handleRemove(index, event) {
    if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
      let todoArray = this.state.items;
      todoArray.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({
        items: todoArray
      });
    }
  }
  handleCheck(index, event) {
    // code to create line through completed item
    this.setState(state => ({
      completed: { ...state.completed, [index]: !state.completed[index] }
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>To Do App</h1>
        <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            className="input"
            value={this.state.term}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="list-group">
          {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
            <li
              style={{
                textDecoration: this.state.completed[index]
                  ? "line-through"
                  : ""
              }}
              key={index}
            >
              <input
                id="chk"
                onChange={() => this.handleCheck(index)}
                type="checkbox"
              />{" "}
              {item}
              <button
                className="btn btn-info"
                onClick={event => this.handleRemove(index, event)}
              >
                X
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Perfect!! I'm still a little unfamiliar with some of the ES6 syntax so I will look more into it!    Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If you hit a problem you can ask here, so I can try to add more explanations to my answer.